# Unable to save image to Android file system from bitmap data

Tags: android, bitmap, save, android-external-storage, textureview

I have an app that captures the phones's camera image and displays it in a TextureView.

When I press a Button, I want to save the image that is displayed in the view by getting its bitmap data, convert it into byte array and then write it with FileOutputStream.

The only problem is that the image is not saved to anywhere. I get no error messages, no exceptions during the saving method, but afterwards when I try to open the image with an Intent, I get 'Media not found.' in a Toast message.

I have these permissions granted in manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I also request for the camera and the storage dynamically on app's first start, and I granted the permissions (otherwise the camera would not work).

Here is my code of the saving method:

```
            val bitmap = mTextureView.bitmap
            val bos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            bitmap!!.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos)
            val bitmapData = bos.toByteArray()

            val file = File(applicationContext.filesDir, "TEST_PIC.png")
            if (!file.exists())
                file.createNewFile()
            val output = FileOutputStream(file)

            output.write(bitmapData)
            output.flush()
            output.close()

            val intent = Intent()
            intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(file.path), "image/*")
            startActivity(intent)
```

I have also tried to save the image into external storage, but that didn't work neither.

Comment: "but afterwards when I try to open the image with an Intent, I get 'Media not found.' in a Toast message" -- first, in your `Intent`, use a concrete MIME type, not a wildcard. Second, use `FileProvider`, not `Uri.parse()`, as you should be crashing with a `FileUriExposedException` on Android 7.0+.

Comment: I don't really understand the FileProvider part of your answer.
I added a provider into my manifest based on this tutorial:
https://www.journaldev.com/23219/android-capture-image-camera-gallery-using-fileprovider

But what should I change in my intent?

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it. :)
Thank you for your suggestion and help!